# Spring batch: storedProcedureItemReader Invalid parameter index 0

Tags: java, spring, stored-procedures, spring-batch, java-stored-procedures

I trying to use spring batch with storedProcedureItemReader 
and always i get this exception 
and i cant found the error i use Sybase at BBDD

```
org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: Executing stored procedure; bad SQL grammar [{call PROCEDURE(?)}]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid parameter index 0.
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid parameter index 0.
```

this is java spring code

```
@Bean
    protected ItemReader<AuditKpi> auditKpiRead(DataSource dataSource) throws Exception{

        StoredProcedureItemReader<AuditKpi> storedProcedureItemReader = new StoredProcedureItemReader<AuditKpi>();
        SqlParameter[] parameter = {new SqlParameter("@INDATE", Types.SQL_DATETIME)};  
        PreparedStatementSetter stament = new PreparedStatementSetter() {

            @Override
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
                ps.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(new Date().getTime()));
            }
        };

        storedProcedureItemReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        storedProcedureItemReader.setProcedureName("PROCEDURE");
        storedProcedureItemReader.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<AuditKpi>(AuditKpi.class));
        storedProcedureItemReader.setParameters(parameter);
         storedProcedureItemReader.setPreparedStatementSetter(stament);
         storedProcedureItemReader.afterPropertiesSet();
         storedProcedureItemReader.setVerifyCursorPosition(false);
         System.out.println(storedProcedureItemReader.getSql());
        return storedProcedureItemReader;

    }
```

And this is my SQL code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROCEDURE (IN @INDATE DATE)
AS
...
GO
```

Thranks for your help

Comment: have you find the answer? can you share one working example